# read from docx by NPOI , get Exception" SettingsDocument parse failed"

Tags: c#, docx, npoi

```
using (FileStream readStream = File.OpenRead(filePath)){
    bool test = readStream.CanRead;
    document = new XWPFDocument(readStream);
```

I want to read many docx by NPOI , but when i read some docx ,show "SettingsDocument parse failed"

and get Exception

> System.ObjectDisposedException

and Message show can`t access the file has cloesd;

[image]

i  want to read many docx by NPOI , but when i read some docx ,show "SettingsDocument parse failed"

new XWPFDocument(readStream) throw exception ,detail like this
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show which call throws the exception? The `new XWPFDocument(readStream)`? Can you also tell us the kind of file you are trying to open: a `.doc` or a `.docx`